# Sed regex printing into a file.txt

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, io-redirection

I'm connected to a MQTT stream, and I filter out the data by entering :

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 |
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p}"
```

into the Ubuntu terminal. This prints the only things that I am interested from the MQTT stream.

Now that I can do this I would like to dump this information into a `qwerty.TXT` file.
I've tried

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 |
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;w qwerty.txt}"
```

and got the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched '{'
```

I've looked into sed regex, and the examples are that `w file.type` writes into the file `file.type` where type can be `.txt` for example.

I've also tried

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 |
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p >> qwerty.txt}"
```

and

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 |
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;1a qwerty.txt}"
```

How can I print my filtered MQTT stream into a file named `qwerty.txt`?

Comment: `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p}" > qwerty.TXT`

Comment: @heemayl if i write `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p}" >> qwerty.TXT` will be appending the filtered MQTT stream into the qwerty.txt?

Comment: @heemay,  thanks, and if I wanted to make this command run in the background with an `&` would it just be `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p}" > qwerty.TXT &` ?

Comment: @heemayl, I've checked into the qwerty.txt, the file is empty. Even though `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p}"` prints data on a parallel terminal. Is there a way of printing the datum inside of the sed command i.e. inside `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;p}"`?

Comment: @don_crissti, I owe you more then a thanks! just writing the file didn't work, writing the full directory (`...>>/home/ed/file.txt`) did the trick though! And to make this run 24/7 in the background I would just need to add an `&` at the end of the command right? from reading various sites/forums `$ some_command &` will run the _some_command_ in the background until its stopped.

Comment: @don_crissti, the code works great, but it prints the same time over and over again :/ this doesn't really make sense because when I just make it run in the terminal the time increments everytime something is printed, but this doesn't seem to be happeing when it's printing in to the `file.txt` regardless here is the [output](http://www.codeshare.io/Jp2nf)

Comment: @don_crissti Works like a charm. I've changed the output so the date is printed in seconds ie. `date +%s` so currently its `mosquitto_sub -d -t +/# 2>&1 | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%s,$0"' | sed -n "/PUBLISH/{N;s|.*\('.*',\).*\n\(.*\)|\1 \2|;p}"` works without a problem! I will try to figure out what the `| xargs ...."+%s,$0" |` part :)

Comment: @don_crissti wilco -if it's ok with you I would like to keep this page in my bookmarks for future referencing. -deleted question posted an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

To terminate a `w` command in `sed`, you need an end of line or an end of string.

You can either embed a literal newline in your `sed` command (which is rather irritating for interactive use) or you can use multiple `-e` commands.

So instead of:

```
sed -n "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;w qwerty.txt}"
```

You would use:

```
sed -n -e "/PUBLISH/{s|.*\('.*',\).*|\1$(date),|;N;s/\n//;w qwerty.txt" -e "}"
```